# D3 scatter chart dynamic axis positions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im using [this](http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/dcd013b5c5f341171b618941693a725b) scatter chart example to achieve dynamic axis changing on data change.

I want to achieve two things:

1 - the X and Y axis intercept at 0

2 - both axis intercept in the middle of the chart to accommodate negative numbers better

This is where Ive got to : Ive managed to get the Y axis into the middle but once the data is changing the X and Y axis are not aligning properly. Could anyone suggest a fix in my update function ? My edited example is [here](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/ab0f2f3f9fac53342959c64c3a2af468).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make axis intercept at 0 in the middle of the chart with linear scales, you should define symmetric domains:

```
var ds = randomData(200);
var xmax = d3.max(ds, function (d) { return Math.abs(d.x); });
var ymax = d3.max(ds, function (d) { return Math.abs(d.y); });
x.domain([-xmax, xmax]).nice();
y.domain([-ymax, ymax]).nice();
```

[Demo](http://blockbuilder.org/etiennecrb/4625720545922de67e512e137032afac)

Comment: Thanks, Ill try that. Just to say, I dotn think your demo does it tho, when you click change data the axis dont match up.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't save my fork. Now the link is ok.